# Checking if page is valid without firing validations from server side

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I want to check if current page is valid for a validation group without showing any validation messages. If I call Page.Validate("ValidationGroup") then it shows all the valiation message but I do not want it.

I just to check if page is valid for a particular validation group. And one more constraint, I have to do this on server side can't do it with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the validators in a validation group, like this:

```
private bool AreAllValidatorsInGroupValid(string validationGroupName)
{
    foreach(var theValidator in Page.GetValidators(validationGroupName))
    {
        var baseValidator = theValidator as BaseValidator;

        if(baseValidator != null)
        {
            if(!baseValidator.IsValid)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
if(!AreAllValidatorsInGroupValid("ValidationGroup"))
{
    // Do something here
}
```